# OS X Server ignores virtual hosts

Tags: macos, apache, apache2, webserver, virtualhost

I have a OS X Server 10.8 [with the Server App]. I have enabled the websites service and I've added the path to `/Volumes/dev1/http` as the root for my Server Website.

I've edited the file in `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and added the following line: `Include /Volumes/dev1/http/.virtual-hosts`

The file at `/Volumes/dev1/http/.virtual-hosts` is something like:

```
listen 80
listen 443
servername "site"
serveradmin "mail@myemail.com"
namevirtualhost *:80
namevirtualhost *:443

directoryindex .index.php index.html index.php
options -indexes -multiviews +followsymlinks

<directory /Volumes/dev1/http>
    allowoverride all
</directory>

<virtualhost *:80 *:443>
    servername site.com
    serveralias www.site.com
    documentroot "/Volumes/dev1/http/com-site"
    rewriteengine on
</virtualhost>
```

The Server completely ignores this file, even though if I put in some random characters and run `apachectl -t` it says that the syntax is not OK.

I've even tried only having `directoryindex .index.php` in this file and it still has no effect - it returns 403 Forbidden, even thought `.index.php` is present.

This exact configuration works like a charm on an older 10.6 Server.

Thanks for taking the time to think about my problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some google-ing and trial and error approach the answer is: when using the Server App in OS 10.8 you need to put the include directive in `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf` **not** in `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`